# How to make a user not have write permission to all the disk files and directories?

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to make a user (identified by uid) unable to make any changes (creating or deleting files and directories) to the disk. It seems to be unrealistic to set the permission to every disk file, and I don't want to make any low-level mount operations which is complex. Other users should not be affected. How can I achieve that? I have root privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). You can control with this a particular user's access to locations. So you can restrict access to a disk's main directory with:

```
setfacl -m u:unwelcome_guest:000 /1/2/3/the_top_of_some_fs
```

I hope `/1/2/3/the_top_of_some_fs` is clear.